# how can I do this without using underscoreJS?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm wondering how I could do this using JUST javascript **without** using undercoreJS? I've been trying different ways but  I can't make it happen! :( Thanks!

What I want to do is to check which is checked or unchecked basically.

```
myArray =[
        {text: 'lean something', done: false},
        {text: 'what ever', done: false }

    ];

function clearCompleted = function(){
        myArray = _.filter(myArray, function(todo){
                    return !todo.done;
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you support only modern browsers (i.e. anything newer than IE8), you can just use `.filter()`:

```
myArray.filter(function(todo){
    return !todo.done;
});
```

If you want to support older browsers, use a loop:

```
var temp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (!myArray[i].done) {
        temp.push(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(todo) {
    return !todo.done;
});
```

If you're on an older browser that doesn't include that method there's a shim available at the above link.

Comment: The shim modifies the Array.prototype and this can be dangerous in some situations if you make use of for/in loops (for item in array) loops.  I'd recommend making your own utility function for this (call it myArrayFilter or whatever makes sense in your app) rather than modifying the Array object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(todo){
    return !todo.done;
});
```